# Reference type OrderByDescending

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.5

I am now using OrderByDescending to sort the elements of an IEnumerable collection and all I am doing is assigning back to the same collection.

```
this.InputParts =
     this.InputParts.OrderByDescending(lazy => lazy.Metadata.Priority);
```

From the msdn, It seems like that it has a deferred return object. (It has a return value, something like what I visualize as a pass by value say in C++)

I guess, there should be something which can perform a reference type sorting.

Say, Instead of

```
this.InputParts =
     this.InputParts.OrderByDescending(lazy => lazy.Metadata.Priority);
```

we just say,

```
//shall itself reorder the collection!
this.InputParts.SomeMSDNFunction(lazy => lazy.Metadata.Priority);
```

(I guess assigning back to the same list might bring up performance issues. BTW, I only guess!)

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: What is that function that could sort using reference ? that "SomeMSDNFunction"..

Comment: What type is `this.InputParts`?

Comment: @Dennis:  IEnumerable collection... (in the first line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the type of `InputParts` is some kind of material collection such as a `List<T>` or an array, functions such as you describe [do](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.sort.aspx) [exist](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3da4abas.aspx); they reorder the collection in-place when invoked.

In the more general case where it is just an `IEnumerable<T>` there is no possibility of "imposing order" on the enumerable object instance because that would require *replacing* the code that produces the enumeration. Since that is obviously unfeasible, the only thing you can do is *wrap* your own sort code around it, which is what LINQ does. The result works as in your initial examples (a new instance of *something* is returned, and that something imposes the sort order).

Comment: thank you.. so, as you say, the only option is to create a new instance of an object which is sorted using LINQ..